# ASP.NET Core Web API - 3rd party web service calling strategies faster?

Tags: c#, web-services, asp.net-core-webapi

I upgraded my legacy ASP.NET web API to the CORE with some adjustments. There is a 3rd party web service I am calling inside of my API. This 3rd party has a response limitation of a maximum of 10 results/codes inside of a single request. There are times it is needed to get 20.000 results/codes from this 3rd party service. I implemented an action method like this below in my web API in order to get the codes, made some selects and inserts into the database, etc. I wonder If I can get those results/codes faster with parallel service calls or something else. In this current solution, a user triggers my web API from a web application first, then my web API calls the 3rd party web service, and the results/codes are displayed on the web application. This current design (web application <-> web API <-> 3rd party web service) forces the user to stay in front of the screen and keep constantly sending requests to the API until successfully fulfilling 20K codes. How can there be a faster solution strategy for my needs?

**Maybe using `Parallel.ForEachAsync` would make it faster?**

Here is my web API calling 3rd party service:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> CallServiceMultiple(RequestDto requestDto)
{
             HttpResponseMessage response = null;
             var customerId = int.Parse(_http.HttpContext.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "UserId")?.Value);
             var coupons = new List<Coupon>();
             GameConfirmResponse gameConfirmResponse = null;
    
             var requestedAmount = requestDto.quantity;
             var requestClientCode = requestDto.productCode;
    
             //ProductCode Conversion
             var productCode = _unitOfWork.ProductCodeRepository.GetByCode(p => p.clientCode == requestDto.productCode);
             if (productCode != null)
             {
                 requestDto.productCode = productCode.gameCode;
             }
                
             while (requestedAmount > 0)
             {
                 var gameRequest = _mapper.Map<RequestOyunPalasDto, GameRequest>(requestDto);
    
                 var count = Math.Min(requestedAmount, 10);
                 gameRequest.quantity = count;
    
                 //Unique reference ID
                 gameRequest.referenceId = Guid.NewGuid();
                    
                 var gameRequestDto = _mapper.Map<GameRequest, GameRequestDto>(gameRequest);
    
                 //Create signature
                 gameRequest = Utilities.Utilities.CreateSignature(gameRequestDto, RequestType.Initiate,_configuration);
    
                 //Set service
                 gameRequest.service = "ABC";
                 gameRequest.customerID = customerId; //Get from token
    
                 //Add initiation request into database
                 _unitOfWork.GameRepository.Insert(gameRequest);
    
                 #region Call Razer initiate/confirm
    
                 //Call Razer for initiation
                 response = await ABCApiCaller.CallRazer(gameRequest, "purchaseinitiation",_configuration);
    
                 //Read response
                 var htmlResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    
                 var gameResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GameResponse>(htmlResponse);
    
                 //Adding initiation response into database
                 _unitOfWork.GameResponseRepository.Insert(gameResponse);
    
                 if (gameResponse.initiationResultCode == "00")
                 {
                     gameRequestDto = _mapper.Map<GameRequest, GameRequestDto>(gameRequest);
    
                     gameRequestDto.validatedToken = gameResponse.validatedToken;
                     //Create signature
                     var gameConfirmRequest = Utilities.Utilities.CreateSignature(gameRequestDto, RequestType.Confirm,_configuration);
    
                     //Transform DTO into GameRequest for calling Razer Initiate
    
                     var gameConfirmRequests = _mapper.Map<GameRequest, GameConfirmRequest>(gameConfirmRequest);
    
                     //Add confirm request into database
                     _unitOfWork.GameConfirmRequestRepository.Insert(gameConfirmRequests);
    
                     //Call Razer for confirm
                     response = await ABCApiCaller.CallRazer(gameConfirmRequest, "purchaseconfirmation",_configuration);
    
                     //Read response
                     htmlResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                     //Convert UTC to Local Time
                     var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Local };
    
                     gameConfirmResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GameConfirmResponse>(htmlResponse, settings);
    
                     //add coupons
                     coupons.AddRange(gameConfirmResponse.coupons);
    
                     //Set service and client code
                     gameConfirmResponse.service = "ABC";
                     gameConfirmResponse.productCode = requestClientCode;
                     gameConfirmResponse.status = 1; //Default Confirmed!
    
                     //Add confirm response into database
                     _unitOfWork.GameConfirmResponseRepository.Insert(gameConfirmResponse);
    
                     //Add Confirm Cancel request into database - Confirmed!
                     var confirmCancel = new ConfirmCancel { referenceId = gameConfirmResponse.referenceId, status = 1};
                     _unitOfWork.ConfirmCancelRepository.Insert(confirmCancel);
                 }
                    
                 requestedAmount -= count;
    
             }
             #endregion Call Razer initiate/confirm
    
             await _unitOfWork.SaveAsync();
    
             if (gameConfirmResponse == null) return response;
             gameConfirmResponse.coupons = coupons;
             gameConfirmResponse.quantity = requestDto.quantity;
             gameConfirmResponse.totalPrice = gameConfirmResponse.unitPrice * requestDto.quantity;
    
             //Manipulate Response in order to send Client Product Code
             var resultResponse = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(gameConfirmResponse, Formatting.Indented,
                 new JsonSerializerSettings()
                 {
                     ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
                 });
             response = new HttpResponseMessage
             {
                 StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK,
                 Content = new StringContent(resultResponse, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"),
             };
    
             return response;
    
    
}
```

Api caller method:

```
public static class ABCApiCaller
         {
             public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> CallABC(GameRequest gameRequest, string url, IConfiguration iConfiguration)
             {
                    
                 HttpResponseMessage response;
        
                 //Transform GameRequest into ProductDTO
                 var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => { cfg.CreateMap<GameRequest, ProductRequestDto>(); });
                 var iMapper = config.CreateMapper();
                 var productRequest = iMapper.Map<GameRequest, ProductRequestDto>(gameRequest);
        
                 if (url == "Product/")
                 {
                     var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(iConfiguration.GetSection("ABC:Url").Value + url);
        
                     request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                     request.Method = "POST";
                     request.KeepAlive = false;
                     var keyValueContent = productRequest.ToKeyValues();
                     var formUrlEncodedContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(keyValueContent);
                     var urlEncodedString = await formUrlEncodedContent.ReadAsStringAsync();
        
                     await using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(await request.GetRequestStreamAsync()))
                     {
                         await streamWriter.WriteAsync(urlEncodedString);
                     }
        
                     var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)(await request.GetResponseAsync());
        
                     response = new HttpResponseMessage
                     {
                         StatusCode = httpResponse.StatusCode,
                         Content = new StreamContent(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()),
                     };
        
                     return response;
        
        
                 }
                 else
                 {
        
                     var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(iConfiguration.GetSection("ABC:Url").Value + url);
                     request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                     request.Method = "POST";
                     request.KeepAlive = false;
        
                     var keyValueContent = gameRequest.ToKeyValues();
                     var formUrlEncodedContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(keyValueContent);
                     var urlEncodedString = await formUrlEncodedContent.ReadAsStringAsync();
        
                     await using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(await request.GetRequestStreamAsync()))
                     {
                         await streamWriter.WriteAsync(urlEncodedString);
                     }
        
                     var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)(await request.GetResponseAsync());
        
                     response = new HttpResponseMessage
                     {
                         StatusCode = httpResponse.StatusCode,
                         Content = new StreamContent(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()),
                     };
        
                     return response;
        
                 }
             }
         }
        
         public static class ObjectExtension
         {
             public static IDictionary<string, string?> ToKeyValues(this object? metaToken)
             {
                 while (true)
                 {
                     if (metaToken == null)
                     {
                         return null;
                     }
        
                     if (metaToken is not JToken token)
                     {
                         metaToken = JObject.FromObject(metaToken);
                         continue;
                     }
        
                     if (token.HasValues)
                     {
                         var contentData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        
                         return token.Children().ToList().Select(child => child.ToKeyValues())
                             .Where(childContent => childContent != null).Aggregate(contentData,
                                 (current, childContent) =>
                                     current.Concat(childContent).ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Value));
                     }
        
                     var jValue = token as JValue;
                     if (jValue?.Value == null)
                     {
                         return null;
                     }
        
                     var value = jValue?.Type == JTokenType.Date
                         ? jValue?.ToString("o", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                         : jValue?.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        
                     return new Dictionary<string, string?> { { token.Path, value } };
                     break;
                 }
             }
         }
```

Comment: If you think you need to query 20K results from a 3rd party API, you are probably wrong.

Comment: I am not getting them at once from the code as you can see. But need some logic to get codes faster or somehow scheduled because this current design (web application <-> web API <-> 3rd party web service) forces the user to stay in front of the screen and keep constantly sending requests to the API until successfully fulfill 20K codes.

Comment: Better to use some background processing instead of running it for long time in .net/http request...

Comment: The speed optimization of this problem lies in the third-party API,
Tomas Voracek's comment is reasonable. In addition, have you considered why the third-party APIs limit the number of items returned each time? This interface may be used for paging. Please follow the third-party API interface documents and current needs. Adjustment.

Comment: I am planning to implement a couple of `IHostedService` in order to schedule in the background. I do think of using `Parallel.ForEachAsync` for better optimization of CPU resources. By the way, I may not fully understand what you mean by background processing. @TomasVoracek

Comment: `background processing` means [`Background tasks with hosted services in ASP.NET Core`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio) here.

Comment: @Cenk Exactly what Jason mentinoned. Also probably good idea to query that API based on some schedule and upsert them to some storage like database or other means.